# How does Windows Explorer determine categories for devices on the network?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-explorer

I have a number of devices on my network: some PC's, servers, and printers.  When using Windows Explorer to view my network devices are separated into two categories:

- Computer (Number of devices)
- Printers (Number of devices)

How can I change the Categories definition of my servers so that they are listed in their own category and not mixed in with the PC's?

For example:

- Computer (Number of devices)
- Server   (Number of devices)
- Printers (Number of devices)

Comment: Essentially each device talks with your computer using a specific network protocol. Depending on that protocol and what information is exchanged the Windows explorer categorizes the devices.

Comment: I am presuming that the device identifies itself using LLT (Link Layer Topology) therefore I am hoping that the Categories value of Computer in this case is stored somewhere in the registry.  Does anyone know where this  categories value is stored?